# How to fetch data in JSON format in complex level based format from DB

Tags: java, json, loops, data-structures

I am in a requirement to fetch the data from DB based on some level and parent id. Attached is the screenshot from DB:

[image]

I need the data in below JSON format:

```
{  
   heading:[21, 'Report Group'],
   data:[  
      {  
         name:[26, 'Monthly Data'],
         list:[  
            {  
               [28, 'My History'], [336, 'Sales 1'], [337, 'Sales 2'], [338, 'Sales 3']

            }
         ]
      },
      {  
         name:[27, 'Current Reports'],
         list:[  

         ]
      },
      {  
         name:[28, 'My Report'],
         list:[  

         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Could you please help me with the Java code that I should write to map this data from DB to Java object.

Here, based on rpt_lvl(i.e. 0) we need to first find out rpt_filter_id(i.e. 21). Then based on rpt_filter_id mapping should be done using next rpt_lvl (i.e 1) and rpt_filter_prnt_id (i.e. 21). and so on..

Please assist.

Comment: If you have started with any code, it would be worthwhile to add it with your question

Comment: any updates plz..